# A WolframAlpha error?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, wolfram-alpha

Consider the equation:
$$
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(x+3)^2}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}=0
$$
that has the solution $x=\dfrac{-3}{2}$ as can be easely verified.

But WolframAlpha gives no solutions ([here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2B3%29%5E%28-2%2F3%29-x%5E%28-2%2F3%29%3D0)). Someone knows why? Or I have some stupid error?

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Comment: In the link, you have $x+3^{-\frac32}$ which is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[2]{(x+3)^3}},$$ not $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(x+3)^2}}.$$

Comment: Yes ! thank you. I change :)

Comment: Assumption: principal root. [Use real root instead](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2B3%29^%28-2%2F3%29-x^%28-2%2F3%29%3D0&a=^_Real). Also [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%28%28x%2B3%29^2%29^%281%2F3%29+-+1%2F%28x^2%29^%281%2F3%29+%3D+0). WA's output differs for things that humans may consider equivalent.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you very much. I never used this option !

Comment: by the way...what you typed into wolfram is not exactly that what you wrote into your question body (there wouldn't be any difference between principal or real root), this would [be](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28%28x%2B3%29%5E%282%29%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29-%28%28x%29%5E%282%29%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29%3D0&a=%5E_Principal) the corresponding wolfram request.

Comment: I see! but in my mind, thinking only to real numbers, $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$ was the same as $x^{-3/2}$.

Comment: You can find a blog post on how WA deals with roots [here](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/04/26/get-real-with-wolframalpha-computing-roots/).

Comment: The funny thing is that Wolfram's definition of "principal root" differs from every textbook I've ever seen (e.g., Sullivan College Algebra R.8, for $\sqrt[n]{a} = b$, "$a$, $b$ are any real numbers if $n$ is odd").

Comment: @DanielR.Collins The proper place to look for that definition is in a text on complex variables where it's connected to the principal argument of a complex number. The *sad* thing about texts at the college algebra level is that they often misuse well established mathematical definitions. Sullivan himself (on page 242 of Algebra&Trigonometry 4th ed) defines a linear function to be one of the form $f(x)=ax+b$, which is completely out of line with the established convention that a linear function should satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. In short - Sullivan is wrong; the Wolfram notation is correct.

Comment: @Mark McClure: I guess that's the definition in an abstract algebra context, but I've never seen that used as the definition in a calculus/analysis context (but of course, it's equivalent in that context).